# Value of archives is different in iOS 6 and iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, archive, ios7

The value of archives is different in iOS 6 and iOS 7 when I archive MyDTO.
Why does this happen?

MyDTO.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *aaa;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *bbb;
```

MyDTO.m

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:_aaa forKey:@"aaa"];
    [encoder encodeObject:_bbb forKey:@"bbb"];
}
```

MyMethod

```
- (void)test {
    MyDTO *myDTO = [[MyDTO alloc] init];
    myDTO.aaa = @"1";
    myDTO.bbb = @"2";

    //data is different in iOS 6 and iOS 7
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myDTO];
}
```

---

**Edit**

*Error occurs in the following steps.*

1. Archive of DTO (iOS 6)
2. Up version of OS (iOS 6 -> iOS 7)
3. Dearchive of DTO (iOS 7)  <- Error!

*Error Log*

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x48, 0xfffffff2, 0xffffffd7, 0xffffff89, 0xffffff80, 0xffffffa8, 0x70, 0xffffff8d)
```

*Normal in the following steps.*

1. Archive of DTO (iOS 6)
2. Dearchive of DTO (iOS 6)

*OR*

1. Archive of DTO (iOS 7)
2. Dearchive of DTO (iOS 7)

I assumed that the value of archives is different is due.

Comment: The format has probably been modified in iOS 7. [It should be compatible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538581/nskeyedarchiver-nskeyedunarchiver-compatibility-on-different-ios-versions)

Comment: I archive MyDTO in iOS 6. Now, My OS is iOS7. I can't unarchive MyDTO. Is there a solution?

Comment: Are you testing on real devices? I've been successful archiving and dearchiving on 6.1 -> 7.0 (32bit, 64bit), and when I copied the data back to the 6.1 system for this simple object, it worked fine

Comment: Yes, I'm testing on real device.
I've added the details.

Comment: Has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: No, I almost gave up (´；ω；｀)

Answer (score 0):

You could transfer a JSON String instead of NSData and add methods for initializing your DTO from a JSON as well as creating a JSON from your DTO. I am using this approach for exchanging data via Bluetooth Low Energy and it works fine between iOS 7 and iOS 8 devices.